# Recursion Not Using Updated Values

Tags: python, wordpress, recursion, woocommerce

I am trying to take a 40,000 line CSV file and turn each line into a valid WooCommerce product post in the SQL database for a WordPress site. However, many of the lines share the same information I am turning into slugs and GUIDs; since each slug and GUID needs to be unique, this raises a problem.

My solution is to write a recursive function that:

1. Queries the database to see if the slug or GUID already exist
2. If it does already exist, update the slug and GUID with a number and run the function again.

The problem I am running into is that when I reference the function recursively in the return statement, it actually doesn't do anything.

I can confirm that the parameters are indeed updating, but the function doesn't actually run with the updated parameters.

See below:

```
    def postCheck(guid, slug, num) :
        cursor.execute("select * from wp_site_posts where post_type='product' and guid='"+guid+"' and post_name='"+slug+"'")
        posts = cursor.fetchall()
        try:
            if (guid == posts[0][18]):
                print('Existing slug/guid: ' + slug + ' / ' + guid)
                slug = slug + '-' + str(num)
                guid = 'http://site.test/product/'+ slug
                num += 1
                return postCheck(guid, slug, num)
        except IndexError:
            return

    postCheck(guid_var, slug_var, 1)
```

I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working. I've scoured StackOverflow, and it seems the primary issue other people have is remembering to include the "return" keyword before calling the function again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is incapable of returning a value to the calling program.  You have no base case in your recursion.  You recur until you get an `IndexError`; at that point you return without a value (i.e. `None`) until you climb the stack back to the calling program.

You need a base case: an `if` that recognizes "this is what I'm really trying to find" and returns *that* value instead of what you get from the `IndexError`.  Alternately, the exception clause could be the place to return that value.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. This is my first recursive function, so please excuse me.

Comment: No problem.  This is how we learn.  :-)   Also, try some effective debugging: put a statement at the top of your function: `print("ENTER", guid, slug, num)`.  This will do a lot for tracing your execution.

Answer (score 0):

If your guid isn't already in the database -- that is, when the test for the `if` is false -- your function does nothing, as it has no `else`, much less any other code, after the `if`.

Putting the `return` before the recursive call means you will never make the recursive call.

A better approach might be to put the search for a new guid in a loop, which continues until a new one is found, and put whatever you want to do once one is found after that loop.

Comment: That's what I want, though. If the guid isn't already in the database, then the code needs to move on and go through with adding it.

The point of the function is to find matches and then update the value until it's unique, then proceeding with the rest of the code.

Comment: It's not here because it's not important. The issue is with this recursive function

Comment: In the context of this function, "the rest of the code" is what you want this function to do when it finds a new guid, so it is VERY important (and the reason you came here in the first place).